# SSRS glitch when previewing report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report using a SSAS dataset, basically gives me a Reps sales figures by customer. The rep field I use has one rep called ST, and within this field at a lower level, includes ST and STS. The report was previously built using a different rep field which was incorrect. Now I have changed it, the data for some reason is not accurate.

When i see the query in the designer, the figures for STS are visible when selecting the ST rep. However, when viewing the report in preview, these figures are now omitted. I have cleared the report data cache which has had no effect.

If I attempt to rebuild the report, then I get the data as expected. Is there any way of recovering the existing report, or does this type of thing happen without a seemingly good reason?

Comment: Have you tried opening the project folder and deleting all the rdl data files.These sometimes get omitted when cleaning a project.

Comment: @AlanSchofield Yes, I have deleted all rdl data files, still missing the data when previewing report. However, data is visible in query designer!!

Comment: Do you have any filters in the designer anywhere (chart/tablix/matrix etc)?

Comment: @AlanSchofield The Rep field is parameterised. There are no filters on the tablix. I get the feeling that I could rebuild the report without any issues, but frustrating that there doesn't seem to be any reason why the data is omitted. I guess i'm just keen to see if anyone else gets unusual behaviour on SSRS such as this.

Comment: I have has similar situations but 99% of the time it's either deleting the data file or something I've overlooked (filters etc) that cause it. The exception was that one time I had made some design changes but they were not reflected in the rdl file (the the designer did not match the code) I deleted the offending code manually to resolve it. So I guess Visual Studio 2015 (that's what I use) does have some issues so you are not alone!

Comment: Was your table or chart grouping by that old field? Chances are you need to update your groups. Quick way to test your theory is to make a new table with everything in the DataSet and see if there's something truly missing.

Comment: @Lucky If I build a new table in the same report, the data is still missing. If I build a new report, the data is there. Given up on a solution, just built the report again!

Comment: @Neal1581 Sometimes it's just what you need to do for SSRS!